# javadoc.exe fails with "error: cannot find symbol NonNull" even though it finds and reads androidAnnotations.jar

Tags: windows, javadoc

I've read a zillion threads on that topic, but still can't find a solution.

I'm trying to generate documentation using `javadoc.exe` on Windows from a bunch of `.java` files that use the `@NonNull` annotation.

It fails with errors such as:

```
C:\Users\<REDACTED>\....\<REDACTED>.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    public <REDACTED>(@NonNull String <REDACTED>, String <REDACTED>) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class <REDACTED>
```

I've spied upon `javadoc.exe` using Process Monitor, it **does** find and read `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\resources\androidAnnotations.jar`.

How do I get `javadoc.exe` to process those source files?